# Spring image upload with @onetoonemapping

Tags: angular, spring, hibernate, rest, jpa

When I upload an image I get an image_id and when I use that id to upload the product the upload is successful but the image_id field in the product table is empty.

I have provided the code below and in case if you're unable to reproduce the issue, you can find the code here https://github.com/My-Portfolio-Projects/FoodBox.git

This is the product entity

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "products", schema = "foodbox")
public class Product {
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    @Column(name = "product_id")
    private int productId;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "price")
    private BigDecimal price;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "quantity_in_stock")
    private int quantityInStock;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "image_id", referencedColumnName = "image_id")
    private Image image;
    
    
}
```

This is the image entity

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "images", schema = "foodbox")
public class Image {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "image_id", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "image_name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "image_data", nullable = false)
    private byte[] imageData;

    public Image(String name, byte[] data) {
        this.name = name;
        this.imageData = data;
    }

   

}
```

This is the controller logic to upload the image and it works

```
//Part of ImageController.java
@PostMapping(value = "/image",consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE )
   public ResponseEntity<Integer> createImage(@RequestPart("image") MultipartFile data) throws IOException {
       String name = data.getOriginalFilename();
       Image image = imageService.createImage(name, data.getBytes());
       return ResponseEntity.ok(image.getId());
       }

//Part of ImageService.java
public Image createImage(String name,byte[] data)  {
       
   Image image = new Image(name,data);
   return this.imageRepository.save(image);
   }

//Part of ImageRepository

   Image save(Image image);
```

This is the controller logic to upload a new product and this works too

```
//Part of ProductController.java
 @PostMapping(value="/products")
    public Product createProduct(@RequestBody Product product) {
        return productService.createProduct(product);
    }

//Part of ProductService.java
 public Product createProduct(Product product) {
        return productRepository.save(product);
    }

//Part of ProductRepository which extends CrudRepository
 @Override
    Product save(Product product);
```

Comment: Do You want to first create image and than connect it to product? Or persist product object directly with an image?

Comment: No I want to first create an image

Comment: To simplify Your question, You could remove unneccessary fields. (other than id and mapping). Also We do not need either html code, nor angular code. More helpful would be to see your request, response body and expected response body.

Comment: The first request is of type Image Entity and the second is of type Product Entity did you check the code above for the controllers

Answer (score 1):

There is multiple incorrect, not best practice in Your code.

- Do not use two different id types. You use int and Integer in Your
  example.
- Do not use CascadeType.ALL if You do not need it. For what You try to
  achieve, You do not need it at all.
- Do use uniform variable names. If Product has field id, with columnName id. Do the same for Image.

For Your example, this are working Objects and methods:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Product extends IdAbstraction {
  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "image_id")
  private Image image;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "image")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Image extends IdAbstraction {
  @Column(name = "data")
  private byte[] data;
}

public Product createProduct(@RequestBody Product product) {
  return productRepository.save(product);
}

public Image createImage(@RequestBody Image image) {
  return imageRepository.save(image);
}
```

First call createImage. Than take id of created image from response and put it into @RequestBody of createProduct. So createProduct request body should look like this:

```
{
    "image": {
        "id": "xxxxxxxx"
    }
}
```

Edit-01:
Also You do not need to override save methods of repository. Just use the default ones if possible. You can call them just as You did in Your example `productRepository.save(entity);` without the need of overriding anyting.

```
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, String> {}
```